# how to draw a rectangle whose the coordinates are stored in a mysql database?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I store my rectangles in the database like so:
1) transfer, by ajax, of the rectangle coordinate to a PHP script;

```
rectangle.getBounds()
```

2) store the rectangle in mysql (with a PHP script)

Now I would like to draw the rectangles stored in mysql database:
1) read the coordinates;

```
$rectangle = $row['rectangle']
```

$rectangle has the following structure ((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
2) transfer, by ajax, to the javascript script.

```
echo json_encode($rectangle);
```

in javascript "$rectangle" becomes "coordinate"
3) finally draw the rectangle

```
var r = new google.maps.Rectangle({bounds: coordinate, ...});
r.setMap(map);
```

Unfortunately a parse error message is displayed instead of rectangles.
Any ideas of my errors ?

Note: hope that this simplified code is understandable. If not I can add code.

Comment: What does "coordinate" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bounds property of [RectangleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RectangleOptions) is a google.maps.LatLngBounds object.  You need to convert the value returned from your database into one.

Parse the coordinate values out of the string and use them to create a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object.

Comment: but rectangle.getBounds is a LatLngBounds object, no ?

Comment: It was before you converted it to a string and stored it in your database.  When it comes back as JSON, it is just a string, it contains the data necessary to construct the object, but it isn't the object.

Comment: Then $_POST['..'] transforms the object in string. Is it not possible to store an object in the database ?